# How can I remove all instances of a single set item in set A from set B?

Tags: python, set

As you can see below, when I open test.txt and put the words into a set, the difference of the set with the common_words set is returned. However, it is only removing a single instance of the words in the common_words set rather than all occurrences of them. How can I achieve this? I want to remove ALL instances of items in common_words from title_words

```
from string import punctuation
from operator import itemgetter

N = 10
words = {}

linestring = open('test.txt', 'r').read()

//set A, want to remove these from set B
common_words = set(("if", "but", "and", "the", "when", "use", "to", "for"))

title = linestring

//set B, want to remove ALL words in set A from this set and store in keywords
title_words = set(title.lower().split())

keywords = title_words.difference(common_words)

words_gen = (word.strip(punctuation).lower() for line in keywords
                                             for word in line.split())

for word in words_gen:
    words[word] = words.get(word, 0) + 1

top_words = sorted(words.iteritems(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)[:N]

for word, frequency in top_words:
    print "%s: %d" % (word, frequency)
```

Comment: I'm confused. If title_words is a set, then there is only one occurrence of any one word... So you only need to remove one occurence. Right?

Comment: +1 to senderle... sets can't contain duplicates in the first place.

Comment: This is non-working code "title_words.strip(punctuation)" throws an error.  And as previous comments have suggested this isn't going to give you any sort of word frequency as you're sucking all the words into a set, which whacks any duplicates.

Comment: @senderle when I run this code it outputs multiple instances of words even after passing through the title_words set, so I thought that there were duplicates, now I'm not sure what is going on...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're saying. The output is coming from a dictionary; dictionary keys are also unique; so there's really no possible way the _exact_ same words could be duplicated. Do you mean that the word count is greater than 1? Isn't that expected? Are there words that appear both capitalized and uncapitalized? I ran the above code and it worked fine on a random piece of text.

Comment: @Ryan, after looking through some of your comments, I have a guess as to what's going on with your code. See my answer below.

Comment: After looking at this question, the comments and my living room wall for some time, I've come to the conclusion that our tapestries need no improvement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote some code recently that does something similar, although the style is very different from yours.  Maybe it will help you out.

```
import string
import sys

def main():
    # get some stop words
    stopf = open('stop_words.txt', "r")
    stopwords = {}
    for s in stopf:
        stopwords[string.strip(s)] = 1

    file = open(sys.argv[1], "r")
    filedata = file.read()
    words=string.split(filedata)
    histogram = {}
    count = 0
    for word in words:
        word = string.strip(word, string.punctuation)
        word = string.lower(word)
        if word in stopwords:
            continue
        histogram[word] = histogram.get(word, 0) + 1
        count = (count+1) % 1000
        if count == 0:
            print '*',
    flist = []
    for word, count in histogram.items():
        flist.append([count, word])
    flist.sort()
    flist.reverse()
    for pair in flist[0:100]:
        print "%30s: %4d" % (pair[1], pair[0])

main()
```

Answer (score 1):

If `title_words` is a set, then there is only one occurrence of any one word. So you only need to remove one occurrence. Have I misunderstood your question?

---

I'm still a bit confused by this question, but I notice that one problem might be that when you pass your initial data through `set`, the punctuation hasn't been stripped yet. So there may be multiple punctuated versions of a word slipping through the `.difference()` operation. Try this:

```
title_words = set(word.strip(punctuation) for word in title.lower().split())
```

Also, your `words_gen` generator is written in a slightly confusing way. Why `line in keywords` -- what's the line? And why are you calling `split()` again? `keywords` ought to be a set of straight words, right?

Comment: I am not sure then why it has multiple occurrences. When I run the code it outputs that the current most frequent word in the text I provide is "me" with a frequency of '6', when I add "me" to the common_words set it then says "me" has a frequency of '5', hence why I wanted it to remove ALL instances rather than just one.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with senderle. Try this code:

```
for common_word in common_words:
    try:
        title.words.remove(common_word)
    except:
        print "The common word %s was not in title_words" %common_word
```

That should do it

Hope this helps

Comment: I tried this method with the same result, though there are '6' instances of the word 'me' in test.txt, when I do it your way and add 'me' to common_words, it is only removing one instance of the word 'me' and it shows as '5' instead of '6', I want to remove all of them.

Answer (score 1):

Strip punctuation out before you make it a set, you do:

```
keywords = title_words.strip(punctuation).difference(common_words)
```

Which tries to call the `strip` method of the `title_words`, which is a `set` (only `str` has this method). You could do something like this instead:

```
for chr in punctuation:
    title = title.replace(chr, '')

title_words = set(title.lower().split())

keywords = title_words.difference(common_words)
```

Answer (score 1):

You just want the `difference()` method for this, but it looks like your example is buggy.

`title_words` is a set, and doesn't have the `strip()` method.

Try this instead:

```
title_words = set(title.lower().split())
keywords = title_words.difference(common_words)
```

Comment: Yes, this is actually how it was before, but when the code runs in entirety, it shows one word as being counted 6 times, if I add that word to the common_words string it then only shows it being counted 5 times, which made me think there were multiple instances of the word but yet only one was being removed.

Answer (score 1):

You've succeeded in finding the top N most uniquely punctuated words in your input file.

Run this input file through your original code:

```
the quick brown fox.
The quick brown fox?
The quick brown fox! 
the quick, brown fox
```

And you'll get the following output:

```
fox: 4
quick: 2
brown: 1
```

Notice that `fox` appears in 4 variations: `fox`, `fox?`, `fox!`, and `fox.` The word `brown` appears only one way. And `quick` appears only with and without a comma (2 variations).

What happens when we add `fox` to the `common_words` set? Only the variation that has no trailing punctuation is removed, and we're left with the three punctuation-adorned variants, giving this output:

```
fox: 3
quick: 2
brown: 1
```

For a more realistic example, run [MLK's I Have a Dream](http://www.americanrhetoric.com/speeches/mlkihaveadream.htm) speech through your method:

```
justice: 4
children: 3
today: 3
rights: 3
satisfied: 3
nation: 3
day: 3
ring: 3
hope: 3
injustice: 3
```

Dr. King says "I Have a Dream" eight times in that speech, yet `dream` doesn't show up at all on the list. Do a search for `justice` and you'll find four (4) punctuated flavors:

- until "justice rolls
- palace of justice: In the
- make justice a reality
- path of racial justice.

So what went wrong? It looks like this method has been through a lot of rework, considering the names of the variables don't seem to match their purpose. So let's go through (moving some code around a bit, my apologies):

Open the file and slurp the whole thing into `linestring`, good so far except for the variable name:

```
linestring = open(filename, 'r').read()
```

Is this a line or a title? Both? In any event, we now lowercase the whole file and split it up by whitespace. Using my test file, this means title_words now contains `fox?`, `fox!`, `fox`, and `fox.`

```
title = linestring
title_words = set(title.lower().split())
```

Now the attempt to remove the common words. Let's assume our common_words contains `fox`. This next line removes `fox` but leaves `fox?`, `fox!`, and `fox.`

```
keywords = title_words.difference(common_words)
```

The next line really looks legacy to me, as if it was meant to be something like `for line in linestring.split('\n') for word in line.split()`. In the current form, `keywords` is just a list of words, so `line` is just a word without spaces, so `for word in line.split()` has no effect. We just iterate over every word, remove punctuation, and make it lowercase. `words_gen` now contains 3 copies of fox: `fox`, `fox`, `fox`. We've removed the one un-punctuated version.

```
words_gen = (word.strip(punctuation).lower() for line in keywords
                                             for word in line.split())
```

The frequency analysis is pretty spot-on. This creates a histogram based on the words in the words_gen generator. Which ultimately gives us the N most uniquely punctuated words! In this example, `fox=3`:

```
words = {}
for word in words_gen:
    words[word] = words.get(word, 0) + 1
top_words = sorted(words.iteritems(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)[:N]
```

So there's the **what-went-wrong**. Others have posted clear solutions for word frequency analysis, but I'm in a bit of a performance frame of mind, and came up with my own variant. First, split the text into words using a regular expression:

```
# 1. assumes proper word spacing after punctuation, if not, then something like
#    "I ate.I slept" will return "I", "ATEI", "SLEPT"
# 2. handles contractions properly. E.g., "don't" becomes "DONT"
# 3. removes any unexpected characters such as Unicode Non-breaking space and
#    non-printable ascii characters (MS Word inserts ASCII 0x05 for
#    in-line review comments)
clean = re.sub("[^\w\s]+", "", text.upper())
words = clean.split()
```

Now based on [Python Performance Tips for Initializing Dictionary Entries](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#Initializing_Dictionary_Elements) (and my own measured performance), find the top N most frequent words:

```
# first create a dictionary that will count the number of words. 
# using defaultdict(int) is the 2nd fastest method I measured but 
# the most readable. It was very close in speed to "if not w in freq" technique
freq = defaultdict(int)
for w in words:
    freq[w] += 1

# remove any of the common words by deleting common keys from the dictionary
for k in common_words:
    if k in freq:
        del freq[k]

# Ryan's original top-N selection was the fastest of several
# methods I tried including using dictview and lambda functions
# - sort the items by directly accessing item[1] (i.e., the value/frequency count)
top = sorted( freq.iteritems(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)[:N]
```

And to close with Dr. King's speech with all articles and pronouns removed:

```
('OF', 99)
('TO', 59)
('AND', 53)
('BE', 33)
('WE', 30)
('WILL', 27)
('THAT', 24)
('IS', 23)
('IN', 22)
('THIS', 20)
```

And, for kicks, my performance measurments:

```
Original                      ; 0:00:00.645000 ************
SortAllWords                  ; 0:00:00.571000 ***********
MyFind                        ; 0:00:00.870000 *****************
MyImprovedFind                ; 0:00:00.551000 ***********
DontInsertCommon              ; 0:00:00.649000 ************
JohnGainsJr                   ; 0:00:00.857000 *****************
ReturnImmediate               ; 0:00:00
SortWordsAndReverse           ; 0:00:00.572000 ***********
JustCreateDic_GetZero         ; 0:00:00.439000 ********
JustCreateDic_TryExcept       ; 0:00:00.732000 **************
JustCreateDic_IfNotIn         ; 0:00:00.309000 ******
JustCreateDic_defaultdict     ; 0:00:00.328000 ******
CreateDicAndRemoveCommon      ; 0:00:00.437000 ********
```

Cheers,
E

Answer (score 0):

Not ideal, but works as a word frequency counter (which is what this appears to be aiming at):

```
from string import punctuation
from operator import itemgetter
import itertools

N = 10
words = {}

linestring = open('test.txt', 'r').read()

common_words = set(("if", "but", "and", "the", "when", "use", "to", "for"))

words = [w.strip(punctuation) for w in linestring.lower().split()]

keywords = itertools.ifilterfalse(lambda w: w in common_words, words)

words = {}
for word in keywords:
    words[word] = words.get(word, 0) + 1

top_words = sorted(words.iteritems(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)[:N]

for word, frequency in top_words:
    print "%s: %d" % (word, frequency)
```